# Using Whenever gem with Rails Active Job to schedule a batch email job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduling

I'm trying to understand how to use whenever properly, or if I'm even using it for the right thing.  I've created a job:

```
  class ScheduleSendNotificationsJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :notification_emails

  def perform(*args)
      user_ids = User.
                joins(:receipts).
                where(receipts: {is_read: false}).
                select('DISTINCT users.id').
                map(&:id)

      user_ids.each do |user_id|
          SendNotificationsJob.create(id: user_id)
          Rails.logger.info "Scheduled a job to send notifications to user #{user_id}"
        end  
    end
   end
```

I'd like to perform this job ever day at a set time.  The job polls to see if there are any outstanding notifications, batches them, and then sends them to users so that a user can get one email with a bunch of notifications instead of a bunch of emails with one notification per email.  I tried doing this with Delayed Job, but it seems it's not designed to schedule something on a recurring basis.  So now I'm trying to do it with the whenever gem, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it up properly.

This is what I have in my config/schedule.rb file:

```
every 1.minute do
   runner ScheduleSendNotifications.create
end
```

When I run whenever -i in the console I get the following:

```
Lorenzs-MacBook-Pro:Heartbeat-pods lorenzsell$ whenever -i
config/schedule.rb:13:in `block in initialize': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::ScheduleSendNotifications (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Should I be using something else?  I'm just learning ruby and rails so any help is very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whenever gem takes a string as the argument to the runner function. Whenever doesn't actually load the Rails environment so it doesn't know about your ScheduleSendNotifications class.

The code below should get the crontab set up correctly to run your job.

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "ScheduleSendNotifications.create"
end
```

From your project directory run `whenever -w` to set up the crontab file. Run `crontab -l` to view the written crontab file. Every minute the system will execute your Rails runner. From there you may need to debug your `ScheduleSendNotifications.create` code if something isn't working.

Comment: ok.  that takes care of the error.  how do I get it to actually run?

Comment: added some info to the answer. if there are more errors feel free to post them

Comment: I updated my question with the full function body that i'm calling.  there's a call there to the Rails logger which doesn't seem to be getting called at all.  I'm assuming the cron job is not running every minute then.  am I missing something here?

Comment: As long as `crontab -l` shows the correct cron your problem probably isn't there. The best way to debug from here is to first check `/var/log/whenever.log` for any exceptions. If that's not helpful then I would try to manually execute the runner from the command line by copy and pasting the command that was generated in your crontab file (crontab -l).

Comment: I don't know much about ActiveJob so you may need someone else to chime in at this point.

Comment: `ScheduleSendNotifications.create`...isn't your class called `ScheduleSendNotificationsJob`? Also, looking at the `ActiveJob` API, you want to call `perform_later` on it, rather than `create`, yes?